# FMX Style issue with modal forms

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm developing a multi-device application for iOS and Android using Delphi XE7 Update 1.
I have a base form from which all forms in my application are driven:

```
object frmBaseForm: TfrmBaseForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  StyleBook = sbStyle
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object sbStyle: TStyleBook
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    ResourcesBin = {
      464D585F5354594C4520322E3501060B4465736372697074696F6E039F00060E....
  end
end
```

It has a `TStyleBook` with a custom style, and following code:

```
procedure TfrmBaseForm.DoClose(var CloseAction: TCloseAction);
begin
  inherited;

  if ModalResult <> mrNone then
    CloseAction := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

When I run my application, everything works as expected. But, as soon as a modal form is shown and closed (e.g. the above code is executed), style of all my forms is corrupted (form and control background color changes to black, ...)

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the same corruption if you use one of the standard styles that came with XE7? Is the custom style based on one from XE7, or based on an earlier versions style?.

Comment: @TomBrunberg The style is based on `Light.Style` (actually, `Light.vsf` as Bitmap Style Editor does not recognize `.style` files) and the only difference is some colors. And, no, the issue does not happen with `Light.style` itself

Comment: @TomBrunberg The same thing happens with `Transparent.style`

Comment: Bitmap Style Designer? That is for VCL projects! You can not use VCL styles in a FireMonkey application.

Comment: @TomBrunberg According to this blog ( http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2014/10/31/firemonkey-styles-part-1-customizing-the-style-template/ ) you can use it to create FireMonkey styles

Comment: Ouch! I need to update my knowledge. This will take some time. Sorry, can't help you just now.